# Replacing Native Relationships with Playa - Update 300 some entries at once

Tags: playa, relationships

I’m trying to switch a site from the Multi Relationships add-on to Playa, the Multi Relationships add-on is just too limiting and Playa would solve the problems.

The trouble is, I have over 300 hundred entries in a particular Channel, and apparently due to the fact that this channel was using Multi Relationships and not native relationships, I can't use Playa’s converter.

For the particular application, it's my church's website, and for each sermon we post, I associate the sermon with a Channel entry for the speaker. Most of the sermons are from my pastor. It seems like I should be able to submit a query that will update the Playa field for each entry to be associated with the Pastor’s Channel entry, and then manually go in a change the few sermon’s that were preached by someone else, but I can’t figure it out. So far, nothing. Any help on how to run that query would be appreciated, queries are my Kryptonite.

Answer (score 1):

Remember to backup your database before tackling any serious SQL updated statement.

What I'd do is assign one of the sermons manually and see what your Playa field gets set as inside exp_channel_data table.

Then run something like

```
update exp_channel_data
set your_playa_field_id='value you noted above'
where exp_channel_data.channel_id='sermon_channel_id'
```

What I'm not sure is whether the Playa relationships table would need to be updated as well. I think it would but you would need to insert new records to that table.